# How to show see more in React Native Web

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

How do I do the "see more" in react native web? My problem is on the `onLayout` and `onTextLayout`.
How do I determine to show the "see more" if its too long?

```
const ReadMoreText = () => {
  const [textShown, setTextShown] = useState(false) //To show ur remaining Text
  const [lengthMore, setLengthMore] = useState(false) //to show the "Read more & Less Line"
  const toggleNumberOfLines = () => {
    //To toggle the show text or hide it
    setTextShown(!textShown)
  }

  const onTextLayout = useCallback((e) => {
    // setLengthMore(e.nativeEvent.lines.length >= 4) //to check the text is more than 4 lines or not
    // console.log(e.nativeEvent);
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <Text
        onLayout={onTextLayout}
        numberOfLines={textShown ? undefined : 4}
      >
        SAMPLE TEXT HERE...
      </Text>

      {lengthMore ? (
        <Text
          onPress={toggleNumberOfLines}
        >
          {textShown ? 'Read less...' : 'Read more...'}
        </Text>
      ) : null}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a long time looking into this and my solution was to implement a really simple component (below) which just limits the lines and allows you to show more. Maybe this is enough for you.

If not you could create a ref and use `measureInWindow` to get the measurement of the text container. `ref.measureInWindow((x, y, width, height) => {})`

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native'

export default function ReadMore({ children, numLines = 4, style }) {
  const [lines, setLines] = React.useState(numLines)

  return (
    <>
      <Text numberOfLines={lines} style={style}>
        {children}
      </Text>
      {lines === 0 ? (
        <Text onPress={() => setLines(numLines)} style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>
          Read Less
        </Text>
      ) : (
        <Text onPress={() => setLines(0)} style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>
          Read More
        </Text>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define a line height and then divide that by the total height of the text to get the number of lines. Here's how I did it.

```
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react'
import { Platform, LayoutChangeEvent } from 'react-native'
        
const LINE_HEIGHT = 30
            
const [numOfLines, setNumOfLines] = useState(0)
const [isInitialLayoutLoaded, setInitialLayoutLoaded] = useState(false)
                      
const onLayout = useCallback((e: LayoutChangeEvent) => {
if (!isInitialLayoutLoaded && Platform.OS === 'web') {
setNumOfLines(e.nativeEvent.layout.height / LINE_HEIGHT)
setInitialLayoutLoaded(true)
}
},
[isInitialLayoutLoaded],
)
```

Then simply use it like:

```
<Text onLayout={onLayout}>A very long piece of text</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Joseph

just update your code

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native'

export default function ReadMore({ children, numLines = 4, style }) {

const [lines, setLines] = React.useState(numLines)
const [showButton, setShowButton] = React.useState(false)

const onTextLayout = (e) => {
    if(e.nativeEvent.lines.length > numLines){
       setShowButton(true)
    }
}

 return (
 <>
  <Text  onTextLayout={onTextLayout} numberOfLines={lines} style={style}>
    {children}
  </Text>
  {showButton && <>
  {lines === 0 ? (
    <Text onPress={() => setLines(numLines)} style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>
      Read Less
    </Text>
    ) : (
    <Text onPress={() => setLines(0)} style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>
      Read More
    </Text>
   )}</>}
 </>
)}
```